# Informatica : taking too long to update on postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, performance, updates, informatica

update from Informatica on postgresql database is taking a lot of time. From the client side the queries are issued slowly. Any configuration change can be made to speed up the update ?

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info to update on this. Still, in such cases - 
 1. Please check if you are using the correct key column in Informatica and its indexed.
 2. Check if your odbc software is updated.3. Also check size of the final table. If its huge then you must need an index.
 3. ALso check if insert or update taking time. Insert can be fast if you drop all index before loading and recreate after the load. You can fire a simple update statement in target from pgadmin to check speed.
 4. Update odbc driver software